# How to set a background color for linear layout programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set a background color for linear layout programatically? I tried following code but not working:

```
LinearLayout footer = new LinearLayout(activity);
footer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 8));
footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("##ffb5d6e1"));
((LinearLayout)v).addView(footer);
```

Comment: The color you use is incorrect. According to `Color.parseColor()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29), correct formats are #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB. Try to remove one #. BTW, since API level 8, [FILL_PARENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) is deprecated. Please use MATCH_PARENT.

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is in your line here:

```
footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("##ffb5d6e1"));
```

Remove the extra '#' symbol so that it is:

```
footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b5d6e1"));
```

I also removed the 'ff'  because you were essentially setting the opacity to 100%, which is done by default if you just only use six character long hex values.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but have made a very **minor** mistake.

The color format that you are using is wrong. From the official docs of Android,

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following
>   names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan',
>   'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey',
>   'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive',
>   'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.

So, basically you are using **a wrong color format** for the `parseColor()` method. Just remove one extra # and you are good to go.

```
footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb5d6e1"));
```

**BONUS**

For simplicity, you can also remove the opacity component from your color. You are setting the opacity to 100% by using "ff" but this the default behaviour as well. So you can just remove this component and keep it simple, like this,

```
footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b5d6e1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is what you need to set the background color

```
please follow the following steps
```

Instantiate the view of the linear layout like
LinearLayout m=(LinearLayout)findViewByid(R.id.line1);
m.setBackground(R.color.back);

Answer (score 0):

Simple Code

```
LinearLayout m=findViewById(R.id.l3);
l3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#84C8A9"));
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to get started.